# Creating indicator variables based on pattern matches

Tags: r, pattern-matching, stringr

I have a text variable and I want to create indicator variables identifying a vector of patterns in the text variable.
For each pattern a new indicator variable should be created (preferably with the variable name identical to the pattern.

create example data:

```
#rm(list = ls())
mydata <- read.table(
  header = T, con <- textConnection
  ('
ID text
6 "aaa"
7 "bbb"
10 "ccc"
11 "a bbb"
29 "a bbb"
30 "bbb"
31 "ddd"
'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
close(con)
```

single pattern matching

```
# a single pattern
mydata$a <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = "aaa", x = mydata$text))
mydata$a
```

Then create a vector of patterns:

```
# multiple patterns stored in a vector
vecpat <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee")
```

And now my question is how to adapt the above code to do pattern matching and variable creation for multiple patterns. 
the new variables show be added to the dataframe, with labels "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", and values ranging from 0 to 1.

I tried to do this with str_match_all from the stringr package. But I am not sure how to handle the resulting object.
the following link (https://rpubs.com/iPhuoc/stringr_manipulation) looks into this, but doesn't provide more info than the quote below:
"If you wanted to extract beyond the first phone number, e.g. The second phone number in the last string, you could use str_match_all(). But, like str_split() it will return a list with one component for each input string, and you’ll need to use lapply() to handle the result."

Comment: is this what you need: `sapply(vecpat, grepl, x=mydata$text)+0L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this...

```
for(i in vecpat){
  mydata[, i] <- as.integer(grepl(pattern = i, x = mydata$text))
}

mydata
  ID  text aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1  6   aaa   1   0   0   0   0
2  7   bbb   0   1   0   0   0
3 10   ccc   0   0   1   0   0
4 11 a bbb   0   1   0   0   0
5 29 a bbb   0   1   0   0   0
6 30   bbb   0   1   0   0   0
7 31   ddd   0   0   0   1   0
```

For a solution without any sort of explicit loop, you could use `outer` with `stringr::str_detect` (which is vectorised)...

```
library(stringr)
mydata[, vecpat] <- outer(mydata$text, vecpat, str_detect) + 0L
```

Comment: Dear Andrew thanks. It works like a charm. Out of curiosity, this is a loop, is there also a vectorised version?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple vectorised function to do this. The other solution here is more of a 'vectorised' approach - although the two do essentially the same thing. I tend to prefer an explicit loop over the use of the `<<-` operator.  You might like to use `microbenchmark` to compare them for speed.

Comment: I compared them for speed with proc.time: on over 1 million records and 3 patterns, it took both about 35 seconds. Yours was a fraction quicker. However, I tried it with 800 patterns (yeah) then it echoed out of memory. the other example worked though

Comment: @mauricevergeer Actually, that got me thinking - see amendment above - I realised there is a vectorised function after all - `outer`.  Probably faster.

Comment: wow, a lot faster. proctime when down from 28 to 2 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same answer as Andrew's but I'm posting it anyway:

```
lapply(vecpat, function(x){
    mydata[x] <<- as.numeric(grepl(x, mydata$text))
})
ID  text aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1  6   aaa   1   0   0   0   0
2  7   bbb   0   1   0   0   0
3 10   ccc   0   0   1   0   0
4 11 a bbb   0   1   0   0   0
5 29 a bbb   0   1   0   0   0
6 30   bbb   0   1   0   0   0
7 31   ddd   0   0   0   1   0
```

Seeing the update, I tried a few more. In my environment, this is the fastest:

```
library(stringi)
cbind(mydata, sapply(vecpat, function(x) stri_detect_fixed(mydata$text, x) + 0L))
```

Comment: dear amatsuo_net, Thanks!, it works perfectly, like the previous reply to my question.